# How to fix Device Manager, Unknow Error, Please file a bug agianst Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, sdk, vmware, android-virtual-device

When i open my device manager in Android Studio and try to run the 'Pixel_3a_API_34_extension_level_7_x86_64'.
I get the error 'Unknow Error, Please file a bug agianst Android Studio'

When i open the logs i see:

```
2023-07-15 21:09:58,512 [ 335428]   INFO - #c.a.s.i.a.AvdManager - C:\Users\RGr\.android\avd\Pixel_3a_API_34_extension_level_7_x86_64.avd\userdata-qemu.img.lock\pid not found for Pixel_3a_API_34_extension_level_7_x86_64
2023-07-15 21:09:58,513 [ 335429]   WARN - #c.a.t.i.a.AvdManagerConnection - Unable to determine if Pixel_3a_API_34_extension_level_7_x86_64 is online, assuming it's not
2023-07-15 21:10:36,962 [ 373878]   INFO - #c.i.i.a.RevealFileAction - Exit code 1
```

I'm using Android Studio on a virtual machine in VMWare Workstation 17 Player.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PBNR.png)

[C:\Users\RGr.android\avd\Pixel_3a_API_34_extension_level_7_x86_64.avd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QG7YC.png)

What i have checked:

- Multiple articles, but can't find one that matches.
- My disk space 84GB Free space
- New device not working